# printing long double goes wrong

Tags: c, long-double

I was working with Dev-Cpp with my TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release. But suddenly got stuck in printing long double values.

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     void main(){
     long double a = 22.0/7.0;
     printf("%Lf",a);
}
```

It compiled well. Then when I ran it it said : "Error 216: This version of %1 is not compatible with the version"

What should I do?

I am not such a good programmer. If you would put some explanations and help me fix this I would be grateful

Comment: TDM-GCC is based on MinGW which doesn't properly support `long double`. At least this was the case a few years ago, I don't know if it's changed.

Comment: You might need to define the `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` macro as `1`, e.g. by adding `#define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO 1` before `#include <stdio.h>`, or by compiling with the `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=1` option (the `=1` part can be omitted as that is the default for a macro defined by the `-D` option).

Comment: regarding: `void main(){`  in C, there are only two valid signatures for `main`  they are: `int main( void )` and `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )` Unfortunately, visual studio allows code that is not valid C.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%Lf",a);`  The C language is case sensitive.  so `lf` is valid, but `Lf` is not

Comment: How do I fix this? Is it my fault or the compiler's?

Comment: @user3629249 Disagree with [only 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558150/printing-long-double-goes-wrong#comment95927823_54558150).   C specifies  `int main(void)`, `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`, or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner. C11 §5.1.2.2.1 1

Comment: @user3629249 OP's `"%Lf"` is valid and matches `long double` since C99.  The compiler is suspect.

Comment: @chux I agree, the compiler being used by the OP is not upto date.  so the `%Lf` is not valid for that compiler  And `void main()` has always been invalid